# gcc implementation of rand()

Tags: gcc

I've tried for hours to find the implementation of rand() function used in gcc...
It would be much appreciated if someone could reference me to the file containing it's implementation or website with the implementation.

By the way, which directory (I'm using Ubuntu if that matters) contains the c standard library implementations for the gcc compiler?

Comment: GCC doesn't implement the rand() at all, its a compiler, all functions come from libaries, in this case from the glibc.

Answer (score 15):

[`rand`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l25) consists of a call to a function [`__random`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l287), which mostly just calls another function called  [`__random_r`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l353) in random_r.c.

Note that the function names above are hyperlinks to the glibc source repository, at version 2.28.

The glibc random library supports two kinds of generator: a simple [linear congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) one, and a more sophisticated [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) one. It is possible to construct instances of either, but the default global generator, used when you call `rand`, uses the linear feedback shift register generator (see the definition of [`unsafe_state.rand_type`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l187)).

Comment: It looks like it is somehow selectable between a linear congruential generator and a "fancier"(sic) algorythm.

Comment: @ninjalj: You're right, and the fancier one is the default. I was wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You will find C library implementation used by GCC in the [GNU GLIBC](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) project.

You can download it sources and you should find `rand()` implementation. Sources with function definitions are usually not installed on a Linux distribution. Only the header files which I guess you already know are usually stored in `/usr/include` directory.

If you are familiar with **GIT** source code management, you can do:

```
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
```

To get GLIBC source code.

Answer (score 0):

The files are available via FTP. I found that there is more to `rand()` used in `stdlib`, which is from `[glibc][2]`. From the [2.32 version](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.32.tar.gz) (glibc-2.32.tar.gz) obtained from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/), the `stdlib` folder contains a `random.c` file which explains that a simple linear congruential algorithm is used. The folder also has `rand.c` and `rand_r.c` which can show you more of the source code. `stdlib.h` contained in the same folder will show you the values used for macros like `RAND_MAX`.

> /* An improved random number generation package.  In addition to the
> standard    rand()/srand() like interface, this package also has a
> special state info    interface.  The initstate() routine is called
> with a seed, an array of    bytes, and a count of how many bytes are
> being passed in; this array is    then initialized to contain
> information for random number generation with    that much state
> information.  Good sizes for the amount of state    information are
> 32, 64, 128, and 256 bytes.  The state can be switched by    calling
> the setstate() function with the same array as was initialized    with
> initstate().  By default, the package runs with 128 bytes of state
> information and generates far better random numbers than a linear
> congruential generator.  If the amount of state information is less
> than    32 bytes, a simple linear congruential R.N.G. is used.
> Internally, the    state information is treated as an array of longs;
> the zeroth element of    the array is the type of R.N.G. being used
> (small integer); the remainder    of the array is the state
> information for the R.N.G.  Thus, 32 bytes of    state information
> will give 7 longs worth of state information, which will    allow a
> degree seven polynomial.  (Note: The zeroth word of state
> information also has some other information stored in it; see setstate
> for details).  The random number generation technique is a linear
> feedback    shift register approach, employing trinomials (since there
> are fewer terms    to sum up that way).  In this approach, the least
> significant bit of all    the numbers in the state table will act as a
> linear feedback shift register,    and will have period 2^deg - 1
> (where deg is the degree of the polynomial    being used, assuming
> that the polynomial is irreducible and primitive).    The higher order
> bits will have longer periods, since their values are    also
> influenced by pseudo-random carries out of the lower bits.  The
> total period of the generator is approximately deg*(2**deg - 1); thus
> doubling the amount of state information has a vast influence on the
>
> period of the generator.  Note: The deg*(2**deg - 1) is an
> approximation    only good for large deg, when the period of the shift
> register is the    dominant factor.  With deg equal to seven, the
> period is actually much    longer than the 7*(2**7 - 1) predicted by
> this formula.  */

Answer (score 0):

From `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git`, I opened the `random.c` file. It turns out, the implementation uses locks around the random generation, so it is not right to use this implementation in multithreaded environment in the hot path.

```c
/* If we are using the trivial TYPE_0 R.N.G., just do the old linear
   congruential bit.  Otherwise, we do our fancy trinomial stuff, which is the
   same in all the other cases due to all the global variables that have been
   set up.  The basic operation is to add the number at the rear pointer into
   the one at the front pointer.  Then both pointers are advanced to the next
   location cyclically in the table.  The value returned is the sum generated,
   reduced to 31 bits by throwing away the "least random" low bit.
   Note: The code takes advantage of the fact that both the front and
   rear pointers can't wrap on the same call by not testing the rear
   pointer if the front one has wrapped.  Returns a 31-bit random number.  */

long int
__random (void)
{
  int32_t retval;

  __libc_lock_lock (lock);

  (void) __random_r (&unsafe_state, &retval);

  __libc_lock_unlock (lock);

  return retval;
}

weak_alias (__random, random)
```

Instead, you can create `thread_local` instances of generators to mitigate the bottleneck:

In C++:

```cpp
thread_local std::mt19937 generator(42 /* seed (can be e.g. time)*/);

void thread_safe_rand(int n) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n-1);
  return distribution();
}
```