# C code stops running

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have the following C code which gives an error:

```
Program stopped at 0x4019b3.
It stopped with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

when debugging.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();

    int n  = 100;int i; int j;
    int N  = 64;int r;
    double complex (s)[4] = {-1-1*I, -1+1*I, 1-1*I, 1+1*I};
    double complex symbol[n][N];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            r = rand() % 4;
            symbol[i][j]=s[r];  
        }
        // Now add pilots:
        symbol[i][11] = 1;
        symbol[i][22] = 1;
        symbol[i][33] = 1;
        symbol[i][44] = 1;
    } 
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

EDIT:

Now I can put it all together after these valuable discussions. Here is the working code with timing and memory allocation and every thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    begin = clock();

    int n  = 100000; int i; int j;
    int N  = 64;int r;
    double complex (s)[4] = {-1-1*I, -1+1*I, 1-1*I, 1+1*I};
    double complex (*symbol)[N] = malloc(n * sizeof *symbol);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            r = rand() % 4;
            symbol[i][j]=s[r];  
        }
        // Now add pilots:
        symbol[i][11] = 1;
        symbol[i][22] = 1;
        symbol[i][33] = 1;
        symbol[i][44] = 1;
    } 
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%3.7f\n",time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done -- if anything - to try and figure out this issue?

Comment: You need to allocate memory somewhere

Comment: This line is wrong: `double complex (*symbol)[n][N] = malloc(n * sizeof *symbol);`. Copy more carefully out of R Sahu's answer. Also you have sprouted bogus `*` everywhere. It should be `symbol[i][j]`, not `*symbol[i][j]` and the same for all the pilots.

Comment: If you don't understand something then look up how it works, don't just guess something and hit compile and then get puzzled when there is a segfault

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes corrected it back.

Comment: @AboAmmar Update your post to show the correct code

Comment: Updated my post. What about timing?

Comment: Ok! I used `printf("%3.7f\n",time_spent);` and got `0.0010000` sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory needed to hold the variable declared by the line

```
double complex symbol[100000][64];
```

is too much for the stack.

Even a simple program like below runs into Segmentation fault when run an a 64-bit machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

void foo()
{
   double complex symbol[100000][64];
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(symbol));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   foo();
   return 0;
}
```

Consider allocating that memory from the heap, for example:

```
double complex (*symbol)[N] = malloc(n * sizeof *symbol);
```

The other problem is that in the loops:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; i<N; j++){  // Problem line
        r = rand() % 4;
        symbol[i][j]=s[r];  
    }
```

You are accessing out of bounds memory. The problem line should be changed to:

```
    for (j=0; j<N; j++){
              ^^ Use j not i
```

Comment: Where there's one problem, there's usually more than one…

Comment: @R Sahu It is not memory. I try `symbol[10][64]` and get the same error. But the debugger points to the line `symbol[i][j]=s[r];`.

Comment: @AboAmmar you are accessing out of bounds of the `symbol` array as suggested by MitchWheat's answer. You need to fix *both* of these problems for your code to work.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I already corrected `i` to `j`. Same error on line `*symbol[i][j]=s[r];`

Comment: @AboAmmar your latest edit screws everything up totally

Comment: Your latest edit shows `r = rand()/4;`. Is that your real code or is that a typ0? It should be `r = rand()%4;`.

Comment: @R Sahu yes it is `r = rand()/4;`

Comment: @AboAmmar, That would not keep `r` between `0` and `3`. That's a problem.

Comment: @AboAmmar it should be `r = rand() % 4;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm 100% sure it is in this line `r = rand()/4;`. because when I replace it with a constant I have no error.

Comment: @AboAmmar you've been told several times now that that line is a mistake  , try reading what people are saying

Comment: @MattMcNabb I used it both ways with the same error.

Comment: @AboAmmar think about what you are writing, instead of guessing

Comment: Yes it is now fixed using `r = rand() % 4`.

Comment: But how to get the time?

Comment: @AboAmmar, With a lot of back and forth, you got over the segmentation fault error. Try to take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a copy and paste error in your second loop test:

```
for (j=0; j<N; j++){
          ^
```

It should be `j` not `i`

[Also, unrelated but you should not use modulus `%` on the result of `rand()` because the low bits are not as random as the high bits. Use division instead.]

[Another answer points out that you may also be exhausting your stack, although I would expect a different error. Worth checking though.]

Comment: Re. the randomness issue, that would depend on which PRNG was in use

Comment: @MitchWheat The same error and, BTW, when I run it a window with `ProgName.exe has stopped responding` appears above the black `.exe` output window.

Comment: @Matt: stdlib.h, rand()

Comment: @MitchWheat `rand()` is a standard C function, the standard does not specify that lower order bits must have lower randomness than higher order bits.  The OP's implementation might have one in which lower order bits do not have lesser randomness than higher order bits.

Comment: I assume you mean LCG. Glibc [defaults to LFSR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932978/gcc-implementation-of-rand) so I question your statistic.  It might be better to link to discussion of this topic instead of asserting.