# Why is glibc's __random_r assigning variables it immediately overwrites?

Tags: c, random, glibc

I was looking for the source for glibc's rand() function, which [an answer here links to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3932978/211160).

Following the link, I'm puzzled about the code for the [__random_r() TYPE_0 branch](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.15#l361):

```
int32_t val = state[0];
val = ((state[0] * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7fffffff;
state[0] = val;
*result = val;
```

What is the point of the `val` variable, getting assigned and then immediately overwritten?  The `random_data` struct that holds state is [nothing unusual](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/stdlib.h;hb=glibc-2.15#l349).

As one would expect, compiling with `-O2` on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) gives the same code if you just eliminate `val`.  Is there a known reason for this pattern?

---

**UPDATE:** This seems it was an aberration in the version linked to from that answer, [I've updated the links there to the 2.28 version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3933182/revisions).  It might have been something that was done temporarily to aid in debugging by making the contents of `state[0]` easier to see in a local watchlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that is indeed some unbelievable garbage code.

There is no justification for this.

And not only is initialization of `val` not needed, the fact is that `state[0]` is an `int32_t`, and multiplication by `1103515245` *will* trigger undefined behaviour in GCC (integer overflow) on any platform with 32-bit `int`s (= basically every one). And GCC is the compiler most often used to compile Glibc.

---

As noted by [HostileFork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247340/why-is-glibcs-random-r-assigning-variables-it-immediately-overwrites/53247379?noredirect=1#comment93379650_53247379), the code in more recent 2.28 reads:

```
int32_t val = ((state[0] * 1103515245U) + 12345U) & 0x7fffffff;
state[0] = val;
*result = val;
```

With this, not only is the useless initialization removed, but the `U` suffix makes the multiplication happen with unsigned integers, avoiding undefined behaviour. The `& 0x7fffffff` ensures that the resulting value fits into an `int32_t` and is positive.

Comment: I should have noticed it's not the current stable version in the link, if you look at [version 2.28](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l361) it doesn't have the extra assignment.  :-/  But you might want to raise that issue about the overflow with them...

Comment: @HostileFork the `U` suffix does remove the undefined behaviour - it just depends on the implementation defined conversion of unsigned to signed.

Comment: @StoryTeller unsigned to signed is still implementation-defined if it doesn't fit

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Oh, the result! NVM me then.

Comment: Although... that `& 0x7fffffff` should kinda assuage that fear.

Comment: @StoryTeller you're correct, fixed. The code is still garbage, it doesn't make sense to use `int32_t` for the state and lose one bit like that, and it just needs to be retained for the sake of backwards compatibility I guess.

Comment: "Less garbage" is a viable software quality metric :P

Comment: Not only that, GCC is a compiler known for taking UB seriously and optimizing based on assumption that programs have *formally* defined behavior (based on a very poor standard language that doesn't remotely approach the rigor needed for a formal language specification), not based on what people would expect when writing in what was described as a "high level assembly language" some time ago.